# Why is the complement of SAT in IP?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, space-complexity, interactive-proof-systems

It is mentioned in Sipser's text that the complement of **SAT** is in $IP$, before $IP$ is formally introduced. After looking at the definition and some of the results, I still don't see why this is the case.

Is this supposed to be seen directly? Or is it easier to show that it is in $NPSPACE$, which would prove the claim since $IP = PSPACE = NPSPACE$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is of course a consequence of $coNP \subset PH \subset PSPACE = IP$. But it can also be proven directly for UNSAT.

The basic idea is reducing the problem to zero-testing a sum over a polynomial in a suitable finite field. It's a bit too technical to repeat neatly here, but I can give you an informal idea of how it is done.

Let's consider a formula $\phi$, define $p_\phi$ to be the polynomial where you think of $x_i$s as variables, replacing $\neg x_i$ by $(1 - x_i)$, each $\wedge$ by $\times$ and each $\vee$ by $+$. Notice that the formula is unsatisfiable iff $p_\phi(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ for all $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$ or equiavalently if

$$
\sum_{x_1 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{x_2 \in \{0, 1\}} \dots \sum_{x_n \in \{0, 1\}} p(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = 0
$$

This follows from the fact that $p_\phi \geq 0$ for any $0/1$ assignement.

The interaction is essentially the prover trying to convince the verifier that the sum is indeed zero. The interaction is done on the sum above modulo a suitable prime to keep computations manageable for the verifier.  The full details are explained [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs278-02/notes/lecture15.ps). The main proof that you need to follow and convince yourself of, is that the prover cannot fool the verifier with large probability.

Comment: Can you expand on "This is of course a consequence of $NP \subset PSPACE=IP$"? Are you saying UNSAT is in $NP$ (I don't think this is known...)? Or are you using the closure property of $PSPACE$? Or what?

Comment: @theQman whoops, it's a typo. I fixed it to what I meant.

Comment: @theQman of course, it assumes that you know that your problem is in $coNP$ and that $coNP$ is in $PSPACE$.. If you do not, Sipser eventually explains all that. The rest of the answer takes a different route.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm just trying to remember why $coNP$ is in $PSPACE$. Is it because $PSPACE$ is a deterministic complexity class and hence closed under complements? Therefore, since $NP \subset PSPACE$ we get $coNP \subset PSPACE$ as well?

Comment: @theQman that's one way to see it if you already know that $NP$ is a subset of $PSPACE$.

Comment: The linked page has expired. Can you update it?